# How to handle when an attribute is invalid?

Tags: c#, exception, constructor, attributes

I have an attribute. Let's call it `SomeAttribute`.
Ideally, it would be defined like this:

```
public class SomeAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MyType[] MyObjects { get; set; }
    public SomeAttribute(params MyType[] parameters)
    {
        MyObject = parameters
    }
}
```

However, due to attributes' limitations, it's defined like this:

```
public class SomeAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MyType[] MyObjects { get; set; }
    public SomeAttribute(params string[] parameters)
    {
        MyObject = parameters.DoConvert(); //basically convert them to a MyType[]
    }
}
```

However, if the strings are invalid, I thought I should throw an exception. But I thought "attributes are special, I think there's must be some thing different about exceptions...". Then I found this: http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/11/23/beware-exceptions-in-attribute-constructors/.
Basically, it says "throwing exceptions in attribute constructors is not a good idea".

So what should I do here? Should I throw an exception? Should I add a bool which returns true if the attribute is invalid?

Comment: What about a class which can only be instantiated by a static method? Like: Var someattribute = SomeAttribute.GetNew(paramters);
The Method could invole your DoConvert method and throw if it fails -if not, it could get you the Object.

Comment: What if only one param/String is invalid, does that invalidate the entire set (the SomeAttribute itself is defined "invalid" at that point)?

Comment: @ChristianSauer I'm using this on enum fields. :/

Comment: @DonBoitnott Yep, it should.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance This is a developer bug/issue, I'd make sure the exception message is very clear, and let it blow up in their face.

Comment: @asawyer So basically exception, but really quite clear?

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance Actually, I'd go the other way.  I would opt for an indicator as part of it to suggest that it's valid or not and process the String problems quietly.  Since it's pass/fail and no "it's half good" state, this would be acceptable.  Of course, @asawyer isn't wrong...if you're passing bad stuff to the constructor, perhaps you deserve a good explosion.  But why _can't_ you receive a `MyType[]` (why isn't the caller responsible for `DoConvert()`)?

Comment: @DonBoitnott Because you can only use certain types on attribute constructors.

Comment: @DonBoitnott My thought was that since it's an attribute and hence is a compile time construct that a bad value means the Dev messed up, so stop the process and give a nice nasty-gram upfront.